# Install rsync with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I would like to backup a dir in Win XP on a Solaris server via rsync. I installed cygwin but when I type rsync I get 'command not found'. How can I install rsync? And how can I install ssh. I have installed Poderosa as ssh client (a sort of putty).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Run your cygwin `setup.exe` again, and expand the categories to find 'rsync' and 'ssh'.

Answer (score 25):

Much easier. Run setup, click through to the 'Cygwin Setup - Select Packages' window, and type 'rsync' in the 'Search' box at upper left. At this writing, this shows three lines, one of which is 'Net'. Expand Net and you'll find rsync. Click the circular arrow icon to mark it for install, then click Next at lower right.

Answer (score 7):

You still need to install the rsync package. Run setup.exe again and go through the packages manually (it's probably in 'networking' or 'utilities').

Comment: On the Select Packages page of the Cygwin Setup installer you can search for rsync and ssh instead of manually going through all the available packages.

Answer (score 3):

When you run setup.exe, the package selection will be set to "default". You need to click on the top-level circular arrow picture until it says "Install" or "Full" (my memory fails me), it will do this for *all* sub-packages as well.

The first time you click on it, wait a few seconds - there's a long delay in getting from "default" to the next option.

That's the best way. All the times I've tried to select individual packages, I've had troubles so I've long since gotten into the habit of installing *everything*.

Comment: The install guide advises against this https://cygwin.com/install.html 
"Q: How do I install everything? A: You do not want to do this! This will install an enormous amount of packages that you will never use, including debuginfo and source for every package"

Comment: @aland, in rerms of storage required, those 'tens of gigabytes' mentioned are are pretty much irrelevant now in most scenarios. And you only have to download once to make a local mirror.

Comment: not sure if we're all talking around each other, but on my Setup selecting "Full" just shows the full package list.  Most of them are still set to "Skip".  But it's the only way to get the `rsync` package to appear.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is rsync, the BackupPC project (OSS) has a slightly modified version of cygwin's rsync that runs without a full cygwin installation, and can even be installed remotely on PCs with IPC$. http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=34854&package_id=88133