# how do I use cygwin to rsync files?

Tags: mysql, linux, cygwin, rsync, file-transfer

How do I do that? Instructions :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cygwin + rsync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807053/cygwin-rsync)

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, download cygwin, install all packages.
Download unison.

```
C:\cygwin\bin\unison-2.32.exe
-sshcmd=C:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe /cygdrive/c/users/yourlogin/Desktop/somefolder/ ssh://server.domain.com///dir1/dir2/
-ignore 'Path */someOtherDir' -ignore 'Name someFile' -owner -group -terse
-batch
```

Comment: *All* packages? Isn't that a little overkill?

Comment: Yes but might as well have them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure all those DBs, programming languages, libraries, shells, mail clients, etc., will all come in really handy!